# Changing validation List rage dynamically

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I want to set up dynamically changing Data Validation List Source range, based on change in value of another cell.

Sheet 1 is my input and output sheet.  I select values on Col A with dropdown list, which has source from Sheet2,Col A.

Sheet2,Col A has five product names which are source for Sheet1 Col A dropdown.

Sheet2,Col B has manufacturing steps related with Product1 of Sheet2,ColA
Sheet2,Col C has manufacturing steps related with Product2 of Sheet2,ColA
..so goes for next 3 columns

I want operation as follows :

IF
In sheet1,Col A,cell A2, I enter *Product1* as value using dropdown.
Then
In sheet1,Col A,cell B2, I wish to select one of the several manufacturing steps which are listed in Sheet2,Col B

ElseIF
In sheet1,Col A,cell A2, I enter *Product2* as value using dropdown.
Then
In sheet1,Col A,cell B2, I wish to select one of the several manufacturing steps which are listed in Sheet2,Col C.

This way, in Sheet1,Col B, I want to have a dropdown lists which are dynamically changing their data source , based on cell value on the left of current cell in Col A

If cell A3 in sheet1 value is *Product1* then the data validation data source is sheet1,cell B2 is from sheet2,col A,

If cell A3 in sheet1 value is *Product2* then the data validation data source is sheet1,cell B2 is from sheet2,col B.

Can this be done ?

Comment: Could you tell us in which software/language you use? I suppose it's Excel but I can't really tell. By adding a tag related to this software/language you have better chance to get an answer.

Comment: The question is in relation to VBA for Excel please.